# Symfony asset cache not working in production

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, caching, assetic

I have been working on a Symfony application which is hosted on AWS. It seems that my image cache is not working properly. The system setup is using VichUploaderBundle, Assetic. I would like to mention I have this application working perfectly (no errors at all) locally on my MacBook.

The cache directory is in `/var/www/myapp/shared/web/media/cache`, this folder is `755` (same for its children), and the folder has the owners `nginx:ec2-user`. When an image is attempted to be loaded, eg. `http://myapp.com/media/cache/resolve/login_logo/bundles/appfrontend/images/logos/linear-logo_small.png` it does not load the image, nor does it create a directory in the cache to contain the image.

A similar issue is happening with the javascript for the application. Although it looks like the javascript is being loaded (the js is included on the webpages), it seems that most javascript features do not work on production only. Some examples of JS packages that are not working are Zenstruck and Swiftmailer. I am not sure if this is related to the other error we have.

There are a number of other issues also caused from javascript errors. The javascript is working perfectly on the version I have running on my MacBook.

Thanks for you help and suggestions in advance.

Comment: did you dump assetic assets 
`php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: @wonde Sure did, I am using capifony with `set :dump_assetic_assets, true` enabled to deploy. But also tried dumping manually.

Comment: @wonde Ended up finding out the assets work if set to 777, but everytime a new sort of asset is made with a new folder it is set to 755 and will not work... With the Javascript I found that if was not writing the contents of one of the JS files to the server with capifony. Any ideas on the permissions issue?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html
this might shed some light on the issue  ...

and you might wanna try adding umask(0000)  in app_dev.php and app.php